# Twython - get tweets only from one user, not to that user

Tags: python, twitter, twython

Fairly new to Twython, hope I'm not sounding too dumb here.

Currently I have Twython listening to the Twitter streaming API for tweets from a single user, then triggering a relay to open a door.  It's working well, but I've found that it will trigger whenever my target user tweets something (good) AND whenever anyone tweets anything to my target user (not good).

Is there any way to have Twython trigger an action only when a user tweets, and ignore any replies or new tweets that user?

Any help much appreciated - thanks for reading!~

Answer (score 0):

you can check the tweet's `user` field (in the json you get from your stream listener) and verify that it was tweeted by the desired user.

look here for further details: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users

Comment: Ah great - thanks for replying.  WIll give it a try later tonight and report back here.